# How to change output device using asioOut

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, asio

Currently working on an audio processor, and I have a small settings menu to change input and output devices, input is simple enough, but I'm not sure how to change the output device. I'm using NAudio, WaveIn for input and AsioOut for output.

Currently I just have:

```
public void InitialiseAsioOut()
            {
                asioOut = new AsioOut();
                asioOut.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);
            }
```

for initialising the output, not sure if I even can change the output device as AsioOut just gets the first available asio driver.